# dataflow pipeline python depency installs but fails to import

Tags: dataflow

I have a simple dataflow pipeline that runs successfully on my local machine:

```py
import argparse
import logging
import ast
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery


def parse_args_set_logging(argv=None):
    """
    parse command line arguments
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--verbose',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='set the logging level to debug')
    parser.add_argument('--topic',
                        default=<my topic>,
                        help='GCP pubsub topic to subscribe to')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # set logging level
    logging.basicConfig()
    if known_args.verbose:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return known_args, pipeline_args


class formatForBigQueryDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def record_handler(self, data):
        """
        Build a dictionary ensuring format matches BigQuery table schema
        """
        return {
            "uid": data['uid'],
            "interaction_type": data['interaction_type'],
            "interaction_asset_id": data['interaction_asset_id'],
            "interaction_value": data['interaction_value'],
            "timestamp": data['timestamp'],
        }

    def process(self, element):

        # extract data from the PubsubMessage python object and convert to python dict
        data = ast.literal_eval(element.data)
        logging.info("ELEMENT OBJECT: {}".format(data))

        # format the firestore timestamp for bigquery
        data['timestamp'] = data['timestamp']['_seconds']

        # construct the data for bigquery
        result = self.record_handler(data)
        return [result]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    known_args, pipeline_args = parse_args_set_logging()

    # create a pipeline object
    pipeline_options = GoogleCloudOptions(pipeline_args)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    # create a PCollection from the GCP pubsub topic
    inputCollection = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
        topic=known_args.topic,
        # id_label='id',  # unique identifier in each record to be processed
        with_attributes=True,  # output PubsubMessage objects
    )

    # chain together multiple transform methods, to create a new PCollection
    OutputCollection = inputCollection | beam.ParDo(formatForBigQueryDoFn())

    # write the resulting PCollection to BigQuery
    table_spec = <my table spec>
    table_schema = 'uid:STRING, interaction_type:STRING, interaction_asset_id:STRING, interaction_value:STRING, timestamp:TIMESTAMP'

    OutputCollection | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        table_spec,
        schema=table_schema,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)

    # run the pipeline
    result = p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

I am trying to run this code using GCP dataflow. To do so I need to install a python dependency, `AST`. I have tried creating `requirements.txt` and using the `--requirements_file` argument, without success. I'm now trying with `setup.py`. Having followed [the docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), my `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='pubsub_to_BQ',
    version='1.0',
    install_requires=[
        'AST'
    ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

I am running on GCP with the following command:

```sh
python main.py --runner DataflowRunner \
               --setup_file ./setup.py \
               --project <myproject> \
               --temp_location <my bucket> \
               --verbose \
               --streaming \
               --job_name bigqueryinteractions
```

However, I get the following error when the pipeline processes data:

`File "main.py", line 47, in process
NameError: global name 'ast' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-54']`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK if you specify `setup.py` via shell command line then you should use an absolute path, also with `Dataflow` try boolean flag `save_main_session` as without it your deployed template won’t resolve dependencies specified in `setup.py`.

Parameters that are not dynamic for you pipeline could be resolved during pipeline construction.

For example, this how you can *hardcode* some of the non-changing arguments you need to always pass so you only need to specify arguments that change from execution to execution:

```py
known_args, pipe_args = parser.parse_known_args()
standard_pipe_arg = ['--save_main_session', 'setup_file=./setup.py', '--streaming']
pipe_opts = PipelineOptions(pipe_args + standard_pipe_arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, using `json` libary instead of `ast`. I would still like to know what I'm doing wrong here.